# If $Y\in\mathcal{L}^1$ and $(\mathcal{F}_t,t\in I)$ is a filtration, then $\text{E}[\text{E}[|Y|\mid\mathcal{F}_t]]=\text{E}[|Y|]$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\operatorname{P})$ be a probability space
- $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$
- $(\mathcal{F}_t,t\in I)$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$
- $Y\in\mathcal{L}^1(\operatorname{P})$ and $$X_t:=\operatorname{E}\left[Y\mid\mathcal{F}_t\right]\;\;\;\text{for }t\in I$$

I don't understand why it holds $$\operatorname{E}\left[\operatorname{E}\left[\left|Y\right|\mid\mathcal{F}_t\right]\right]=\operatorname{E}\left[|Y|\right]\tag{1}$$

---

$(1)$ would imply $$\operatorname{E}\left[\left|Y\right|\mid\mathcal{F}_t\right]=|Y|\;\;\;\color{blue}{\operatorname{P}\text{-almost surely}}$$
So, $Y$ would need to be $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable. I really don't understand why this should hold.

---

*Please note:*

A random variable $Z$ is called **conditional expectation** of $X$ given $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ $:\Leftrightarrow$

- $Z$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable
- $\operatorname{E}[1_AX]=\operatorname{E}[1_AZ]$ for all $A\in\mathcal{F}$

We write $\operatorname{E}[X\mid\mathcal{F}]=:Z$.

Comment: No (1) does not imply that. Likewise E(U)=E(V) does not imply U=V P-almost surely.

Comment: @Did You're right. But we've got $\operatorname{E}[X]=\operatorname{E}[Y]$ $\Rightarrow$ $X=Y$ almost surely, if $X\ge Y$ almost surely. I'd consufed that.

Comment: It is **not** true that $E[|Y||\mathcal{F}_t]\leq |Y|$ almost surely, nor is the reverse true.

Comment: No, @Shalop's point is different and, should I admit, slightly subtler than mine (and I see nothing wrong with the notations in this comment). Say, 0/oxbadfo/00/od, what are you playing at?

Comment: @Did He has edited his comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X$ is any random variable, and $\mathcal{H} \subset \mathcal{A}$ is any sub-sigma-algebra, then by the definition of conditional expectation, it is always true that $$E[E[X|\mathcal{H}]] = \int_{\Omega} E[X|\mathcal{H}] dP = \int_{\Omega} X dP = E(X)$$ Now just apply this when $X=|Y|$ and $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{F}_t$.

As Did has pointed out, the equality of the expectations does not imply a.s. equality of the random variables.